# NSNotificationCenter Syntax

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I have this line of code but it is in an older version of swift and I have heard that the syntax has been changed. The code is written below. Telling its current syntax in Xcode 11 would be very helpful.

I have also researched a lot about the changes but could not find anything

the code  inside the DispatchQueue.main.async is the older one for which I need the newer syntax

The syntax(as of the older version) is written below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(  The parameters of the code  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `NotificationCenter` and it will be:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Name Here, object: nil or Any)
 }
```

Comment: Does importing MultipeerConnectivity also imports NotificationCenter....... as I am able to write the code inside     DispatchQueue.main.async    without importing NotificationCenter?